# Can't get Ruby on Rails to work on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a follow up to an earlier quesiton. I just installed Ruby on Rails using the rails installer (www.railsinstaller.org) but when I try to run any commants be it `gem -v` or `rails new sample` I get an error message saying:

```
Failed to load C:/Users/Zack/.gemrc due to permissions problem.
```

ANY ideas what to do would be very much appreciated. (Note that this is all being run on windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

Was this just the only error you received in the console? Also have you checked if this file exists in the directory it is pointing to. if so what is in it. If you happen something like the following in the `.gemrc` you should have something like the following:

```
"gem": "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
```

This should work, providing this file exists. This can be caused when you installed Ruby using admin and then the file is created. For supported information check the following SO question this may also support you [Ruby gem listed, but wont load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260561/ruby-gem-listed-but-wont-load-gem-in-user-dir-not-ruby-dir)

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are two files `.gemrc` like in `C:/Users/Zack/.gemrc` and `C:/ProgramData/gemrc/.gemrc`. Verify and delete this last.